# Where do I store user personal information

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, backend

I am creating an application in which a user registers with a username, email, and password.
This data is stored in one table.
But then the user enters profile information such as photo, bio, activity and such. Do I store this data in the same table as the username, email, and password? Or do I create another table in which I link those in some way?

Answer (score 2):

you can create a different table UserProfile with OneToOne relation.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOne(User, unique=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=140)  
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=140)  
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)
```

Then  in settings.py:

```
 AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

Comment: The setting is not used since django 1.7 according to the deprecation list https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-7

Comment: @JanMalte thanks updated answer . he needs just User model to assign auth model.

Answer (score 0):

You want to extend User model to have other information. The recomended approach for this is to create another model like Profile and setup OneToOne relation to the User.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table that have the information you want to store but the most important thing is to connect the new table with the userid from user id

```
CREATE TABLE USER_INFORMATIONS(
Information_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
USER_ID (int or varchar acoording to the user table),
…
FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES Users(Id)
);
```